# Could you help me translate the sentence?

Tags: translation, idiom

I would like to ask for help in translating this sentence into English.

> **또 백지 수표를 쓸 수는 없지。**

The situation is as follows. Two people, a girl and a guy, make a bet. The guy asks the girl to make the same bets that she once made in the past with another person. The next thing that comes up is this phrase.

When translating through Papago, I got **"You can't write a blank check again"**.

Does this sentence have something to do with the idioms **"give someone a blank check"** and **"carte blanche"**?

*Does that mean she doesn't want to give the same carte blanche to him? Or that it would give carte blanche to her?*

Comment: The former translation is correct. She means that she can't give him a carte blanche again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing a blank check means giving someone a blank check, as you've guessed.

Given your context, I think she meant to say "I'm not offering/betting a blank check this time, even though I did so last time."

FYI, Koreans don't have personal checks. So, any Korean phrases regarding 백지수표 comes from "giving someone a blank check" idiom. In Korean, "writing a check to someone" and "giving someone a check" both sound natural and mean the same thing.

In contrast, when they say 수표(not 백지수표), they have a different version of checks issued by commercial banks, which are not really common anymore.

FYI2, "또 백지 수표를 쓸 수는 없지." does not have a Subject of the sentence. It's exactly why Papago had to make a wild guess WHO is not writing a check. This might be the reason why you were confused with the translation. You should note that English sentences must have a Subject in a sentence, while Korean sentences don't really have to. So, you would get much better results using Papago, if you add the right subject in the Korean sentence as necessary.